# Create references to classes in class variables and instantiate them in __init__

Tags: python, oop

I've recently seen quite a bit of the following pattern in Python:

```
class Foo: pass

class Bar:
    foo_class = Foo

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = self.foo_class()
```

As I understand, the `Bar` class first creates a reference to the `Foo` class as a class variable `foo_class` and then creates the instance of `Foo` in `__init__`. Is there any advantages of it instead of just instantiating `Foo` directly in `__init__`?

```
class Foo: pass

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
```

Comment: I've always had trouble understanding design patterns, but this is an application of the Factory pattern, isn't it? Can someone confirm that?

Comment: by assigning the class ref to a variable, we can easily change the class we want. ie. change happens to be in one place

Comment: @Aran-Fey Probably? I'm looking at [this Python example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Python), and it seems clear that `make_room` could just be a reference to a class rather than an abstract method.

Comment: @chepner Yeah, that was pretty much my train of thought as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some small benefit, as you are no longer hard-coding the reference to `Foo` in a place where you cannot change it. In the first example, you can change the value of `Bar.foo_class` if you want subsequent instances of `Bar` to use something other than `Foo`. In the second example, there's no easy way to do that.

An even *better* approach, though, would be to parameterize `__init__` itself to accept a class to use instead. The class attribute would just be a default:

```
class Bar:
    foo_class = Foo

    def __init__(self, foo_class=None):
        if foo_class is None:
            foo_class = self.foo_class
        self.foo = foo_class()
```

If `foo_class` is *only* used by `__init__`, you can dispense with the class attribute altogether and set a default value for the parameter instead.

```
class Bar:

    def __init__(self, foo_class=Foo):
        self.foo = foo_class()
```

(If `Bar.foo_class` *is* used outside of `__init__`, you would probably need to make sure that there aren't any problems with `self.foo` having been created using a possibly different class.)

Comment: A clear explanation. Thank you.
Although it gets me thinking - if you are not planning to change `Bar.foo_class` somewhere down the line, there is really no point in doing it? YAGNI

Comment: @taurijuhkam In production use, no. For *testing*, though, it provides a convenient hook for replacing something with effects (like database connections, I/O, etc) with a pure value. For example, `self.foo` might be a file handle in production, but for testing you might want an instant of `StringIO`. Being able to replace a class that opens a file with a class that provides static data would make testing easier.

Comment: understood. Thank you for providing a use case, makes it clearer

Comment: Basically: imagine where you might want to use `mock.patch` in a test, and design so that you don't need it :)